# Knockout Error with QUnit and Chutzpah

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, qunit, chutzpah

I have an error I'm getting when I run my JavaScript tests in browser using QUnit and Chutzpah. The error I'm getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null knockout-2.2.1.js:12" has anyone experienced this error before using QUnit and Knockout? I don't get the error when I run my application so I'm a little lost as to why it is showing up now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually happens when `ko.applyBindings` is called in the `head` of your page, as the `body` is not set yet.  Make sure that `ko.applyBindings` is called at the bottom of the page or in a ready block.

Comment: turns out i was including a separate view model in another file that was doing just this! thanks!